# TFS MVC Application Build Reference Problem

Tags: tfs

> c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets(0,0):
>   warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate
>   the assembly "System.Web.Mvc, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35, processorArchitecture=MSIL". Check to
>   make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required
>   by your code, you may get compilation errors.

I am getting this Error message when I build my MVC application.

Do I need to give any additional reference path in TFS.proj file?

```
<ItemGroup>
    <!--  ADDITIONAL REFERENCE PATH
     The list of additional reference paths to use while resolving references. For example:

         <AdditionalReferencePath Include="C:\MyFolder\" />
         <AdditionalReferencePath Include="C:\MyFolder2\" />
    -->
  </ItemGroup>
```

Basically its saying some .dll file is missing?